# Creating a flag using indexes

Tags: stata

I'm looking to build flags for students who have repeated a grade, skipped a grade, or who have an unusual grade progression (e.g. 4th grade in 2008 and 7th grade in 2009). My data is unique at the student id-year-subject level and structured like this (albeit with more variables):

```
id    year    subject    tested_grade    
1     2011      m            10            
1     2012      m            11                  
1     2013      m            12
2     2011      r            4
2     2012      r            7
2     2013      r            8
3     2011      m            6
3     2013      m            8
```

This is the code that I've used:

```
sort id year grade
gen repeat_flag = . 
    replace repeat_flag = 1 if year!=year[_n+1] & grade==grade[_n+1] ///
        & subject!=subject[_n+1] & id==id[_n+1]
    replace repeat_flag = 0 if repeat_flag==.
```

One problem is that there are a lot of students who took a test in say 6 grade, didn't take one in 7th and then took one in 8th grade. This varies across years and school districts, as certain school districts adopted tests in different years for different grade levels. My code doesn't account this.

Regardless though I think there must be more elegant ways to do this and as a side note I wanted to know if the use of indexes is appropriate for a problem like this. Thanks!

**Edit**
Included a sample of what my data looks like above in response to one of the comments below. If still not clear any feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Why the down vote? Please give a reason so I can make changes in order to improve the question.

Comment: Not downvoted by me, but I'm having trouble imagining how your data are structured - too much is left to the reader's imaginative interpretation of what you've written - so I won't hazard an answer to your question. To respond to the downvote, you might consider reviewing the information in the Help Center on asking questions, specifically http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @WilliamLisowski Thanks for the feedback. I'll see if I can restructure the question in a way that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may seem anomalous are students progressing faster or more slowly in tested grade than the passage of time would imply. That's possibly just one line for the grunt work:

```
clear 
input id    year  str1  subject    tested_grade    
1     2011      m            10            
1     2012      m            11                  
1     2013      m            12
2     2011      r            4
2     2012      r            7
2     2013      r            8
3     2011      m            6
3     2013      m            8
end 
bysort id (year) : gen flag = (tested - tested[_n-1]) - (year - year[_n-1])  
list if flag != 0 & flag < . , sepby(id) 

     +---------------------------------------+
     | id   year   subject   tested~e   flag |
     |---------------------------------------|
  5. |  2   2012         r          7      2 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```